# How to skip view caching on certain routes, with laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, caching, routes

I have route cache enable on my laravel 5 project.
I'd like to skip the caching on particular routes views.

Then I found this post on internet:

https://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/invalidate-browser-cache-route-middleware

It's quite old so I adapted like the following:

Added in : Http/Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
....
 'nohttp-cache' => NoHttpCache::class,
....
];
```

Created class in : Http/Middleware/NoHttpCache.php

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
//use Illuminate\Http\Response;
//use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response as SymfonyResponse;

class NoHttpCache  {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        // This step is only needed if you are returning
        // a view in your Controller or elsewhere, because
        // when returning a view `$next($request)` returns
        // a View object, not a Response object, so we need
        // to wrap the View back in a Response.
//        if ( ! $response instanceof SymfonyResponse)
//        {
//            $response = new Response($response);
//        }

        /**
         * @var  $headers  \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag
         */
        $response->header('Pragma', 'no-cache');
        $response->header('Expires', 'Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
        $response->header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, must-revalidate, no-store, max-age=0, private');

        return $response;
    }
}
```

I think there's no reason in Laravel 5 to wrap  $response in Response.
Then by simply adding browser cache "invalidation" directives....

It seems to work on a test route adding the middleware like:

in code/routes/web.php

```
 ....
 Route::get('/', 'MyController@index')->name('test')->middleware('nohttp-cache');
 ....
```

Now question are...

- is this the right approach to skip caching on certain routes when route cache is enable globally?
- Do you see any major issue on the middleware found?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel Page cache plugin by Joseph Silber designed to cache HTTP GET responses for fast page load.

Here is a link. Hope this help.

https://github.com/JosephSilber/page-cache

Comment: Nice package... I guess the interesting the part is about "Customizing what to cache". But I don't actually see advance to include the whole package in Laravel when the framework itself gives you already the chance of caching.